# Wanting to find out if these palm trees are alive or they dead and what are they

Tags: palm

[image: Brown-leaved palm]

Are they pygmy palms and are they alive or they dead?

Comment: Whatever they are, the topgrowth looks pretty dead - but are you sure they are not grasses of some type? Its just there's a couple of stems that almost look like grass seed heads towards the ends. Many of those die back in winter like this...

Comment: The record cold that global warming  brought to TX has killed many plants . So many that I am just waiting to see what lives .Damage is spotty  ;  some azaleas look dead and one ( macrantha ) is 90 % in bloom.  I have no answer because somethings I thought would live ( gardenia) seem dead , and others like redbud are blooming like nothing happened.

Comment: Thanks Worried about the cold weather has killed them and now they are not grass it is pygmy palms! Idk what to do get more and dig them up or leave them alone and see.